# Routing based on indices in an array in rails 3 using mongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper

I have two models, Trip and Day, with a one-to-many relationship. For the time being I do not want to make Day an embedded document.

```
class Day
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ...
  key :trip_id, ObjectId
  belongs_to :trip
end

class Trip
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ...
  key :day_ids, Array
  many :days, :in => :day_ids
end
```

I would like to be able to create routes that look like this:

```
/trips/:trip_id/days/:index_of_day
```

Where `:index_of_day` would be used to find the nth day in a trip `@trip.days[:index_of_day]`, so a person could easily navigate to the first, second, etc. day of a trip.

Currently my route.rb file looks like this:

```
resources :trips do
  resources :days
end
```

Which generates the default routes `/trips/:trip_id/days/:day_id`.

One partway solution I had was to put in my route.rb file

```
match 'trips/:trip_id/day/:id' => 'days#show'
```

And then in my Days Controller

```
def show
  @day = Trip.find(params[:trip_id]).days(params[:id].to_i)
  ...
end
```

This sort of worked except all of the helpers like `trip_day_path` automatically redirect using the day id, not the day index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your helpers to use the index instead of the day id, you can define `to_param` in your `Day` model.  Rails calls `to_param` on your object to find out what to put in the URL.

```
class Day
  # ...

  # many :in is for many-to-many, but you are using it for one-to-many
  # either way, many :in doesn't have an inverse yet
  def trip
    Trip.first('day_ids' => self.id)
  end

  def to_param
    trip.days.find_index(self)
  end
end
```

You'll notice that's kind of hackish, which is a code smell.

Comment: Thanks. I was warned against modifying to_param, but I think it could be a cleaner solution than what I have going currently. If I didn't use :in how would I know which days were included?

Comment: If you use many w/o :in, then it'll be a standard many-to-many:

`class Day
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :trip_id, ObjectId
  belongs_to :trip
end

class Trip
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :days
end`

That will just work.  Unfortunately, you won't be guaranteed that all your days will come back in order.  You might have to add another key to ensure that, or declare your association like this:

`many :days, :order => :date.asc`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that it would just work without creating a day_ids array of my own, thanks.